# RandomReal in combination with NormalDistribution

Tags: random, distributions

I am normally not working with Mathematica, but I have to understand a code written in i!

Can some body say what the arguments and parameters of code below say?

```
RandomReal[NormalDistribution[mz, (mz - sz)/1.64485], nd]
```

Comment: Not sure that should work...? It looks like it should be [`RandomVariate`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RandomVariate.html). In the future, look this up in the docs, e.g. by looking up the docs for [`NormalDistribution`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NormalDistribution.html), but `RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[mz, (mz - sz)/1.64485], nd]` would mean you'd take `nd` samples from the normal distribution centered at `mz` with std. dev. `(mz - sz)/1.64485`.

Comment: Thanks @b3m2a1 Actually after 'nd' there is one more parameter as 'mz'. but it is editted and deleted:). but what you explained is very clear. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah I deleted that because it wasn't valid syntax and thus meant nothing without some enclosing context. If you would like it back you can re-edit it, but if you do you'll be missing something wrapping `RandomReal`.

Comment: Oh, ok! may be the code is incorrect I ll check it

Comment: @b3m2a1 `RandomReal` was the [original](https://reference.wolfram.com/legacy/v6/tutorial/PseudorandomNumbers.html#133927594) way to do this, and it still works in version 10.1 at least.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Please post an answer, as this is valuable information for those who deal with old code.  I retracted my close vote after reading your comment.

Comment: the code is written with 10.1 version you are right. the whole code includes also if statement. it is: If[sz < mz,  RandomReal[NormalDistribution[mz, (mz - sz)/1.64485], nd], mz]. It make sense now with 'mz'.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Szabolcs](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/12/szabolcs) encouraged me to post this as an answer.  The use of [`RandomReal`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RandomReal.html) and [`RandomInteger`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RandomInteger.html) with statistical distributions was introduced, I believe, in version 6, prior to the introduction of [`RandomVariate`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RandomVariate.html) in version 8.  This can be seen by looking at the [*Mathematica* legacy documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/history/), specifically version 6 tutorials:

- [Random Number Generation](https://reference.wolfram.com/legacy/v6/tutorial/RandomNumberGeneration.html)

  > The functions RandomReal, RandomInteger, and RandomComplex generate uniformly distributed random numbers. RandomReal and RandomInteger also generate numbers for built-in distributions.
- [Continuous Distributions](https://reference.wolfram.com/legacy/v6/tutorial/ContinuousDistributions.html)

  > RandomReal[*dist*] gives pseudorandom numbers from the specified distribution.
  >
  > RandomReal[*dist*, *dims*]   pseudorandom array with dimensionality *dims*, and elements from the specified distribution
- [Discrete Distributions](https://reference.wolfram.com/legacy/v6/tutorial/DiscreteDistributions.html)

  > RandomInteger[*dist*] pseudorandom number with specified distribution
  >
  > RandomInteger[*dist*, *dims*]    pseudorandom array with dimensionality *dims*, and elements from the specified distribution

Although this syntax is now deprecated in favor of the unifying `RandomVariate` it nevertheless remains valid, confirmed through the current version 12.0.

---

To answer the question actually asked, consult the documentation for [`NormalDistribution`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NormalDistribution.html)

> NormalDistribution[*μ*, *σ*]
>
> represents a normal (Gaussian) distribution with mean *μ* and standard deviation *σ*.

So your code requests `nd` samples of a normal distrubiton with a mean `mz` and a SD of `(mz - sz)/1.64485`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. it is a very useful info for me because the programmer wants to update the version for the program that he wrote. the parameters of distribution that I asked are also clear. Thanks!!